# About the Lebesgue integrability of $f$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $f \ge 0$ be a measurable function on a measurable subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Suppose there exits a sequence of measurable subset $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$  of $E$ such that 
$$m(E\setminus E_k)<\frac{1}{k}\quad \textrm{ and }\quad \lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{E_k} f(x)dx<\infty.$$ Show that $f$ is integrable on $E$.

*proof:*

Consider 
$$
f_k:=\chi_{E_k}f \Longrightarrow \lim_{k\to \infty}f_k=f \textrm{ a.e on }E \quad \textrm{and}\quad f_k\ge 0.
$$
We can see 
\begin{align*} 
\int_{E}f dm&=\int_{E}\left(\liminf_{k \to \infty} f_k \right)dm \leq \liminf_{k \to \infty}\int_{E}f_k dm \quad \textrm{by Fatou's Lemma} \\ 
=&\liminf_{k \to \infty}\int_E \chi_{E_k}f dm\leq \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{E_k}f dm <\infty \quad \textrm{by hypothesis}
\end{align*}

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Should that be $>0$ in the second inequality?

Comment: Sorry, you're accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: apply Fatou's lemma to the sequence of functions $f_k = f 1_{E_k}$.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just used your hint for the right integral, hope it's okay. I just wonder if the same trick might be applied for the left integral.

Comment: @CharlesSeife: You don't need to do anything with the integral over $E^c$ at all and it is much better if you just do all your analysis over $E$ itself.  But one of the key steps is your claim that $\lim f_k = f$.  This is only true almost everywhere on $E$, and you should carefully prove this step.  Once you have this, you should use Fatou to show that $$\int_E f \le \liminf \int_E f_k = \liminf \int_{E_k} f.$$

Comment: Got it, I guess when we prove that $m(\{x \in E: f_k(x) \nrightarrow f(x)\})=0$, we must use the hypothesis that $m(E\setminus E_k)<1/k$. Sorry, I'm lost to prove it.

Comment: Actually, I take it back.  I don't think it's necessarily true that that $f_k \to f$ almost everywhere on $E$.  However, it is true for some subsequence of the $f_k$.  One approach is to note that $f_k \to f$ in measure, and then use the theorem that some subsequence therefore converges to $f$ almost everywhere.  Another is to choose a subsequence $E_{k_j}$ for which $\sum m(E \setminus E_{k_j}) < \infty$ and use the Borel-Cantelli lemma (which is basically how you prove the theorem previously mentioned).

Comment: It makes sense. It'll be the first time I'll use  Borel-Cantelli Lemma. Thanks a lot for your time.